# NVidia NSight does not see shader resource names (DX12)

Tags: nsight, directx-12

I am debugging a graphics app using NVidia Nsight and need to see names of shader resources as they were declared in hlsl. But in NSight I see just "unnamed by reflection" label, as in attachment. Reflection was not stripped by compiler, I've read the name I need from reflection and saved to text file(like "Name": "BaseColorTexture") so it should be in shader data blob; -Zi compiler option used. DirectX 12 and DXC compiler is used, dxil intermediate, shader model 6.0, NVidia Nsight 2020, "Collect Shader Reflection" option is on. Could you please tell the possible reason of it and how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue was caused by difference in dxcompiler.dll (dxc compiler) used by NSight(copied from windows sdk at install time) and used by my application(compiled in-place from latest official sources), updating dll for NSight folder solved issue.